# spring security database authentication HikariPool-1 error

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-security

**I get spring security database authentication HikariPool-1 error.**
I want to access the rest api with the user and password I created in the database, but I got an error
I created a bcrypt password using the [Bcrypt](https://bcrypt-generator.com/) site.
My password is : `$2y$12$rdewmMOgQBinmLvOw4oiCenOS0n3vs64ri2CT1Nmh8u8KiuZGyD7C`
It means "mutlu1234"

I cannot access the rest api even though I have entered the password and username. It asks me username and password in endless ways. How can I prevent this? What do I need to change

***Spring security error log:***

```
2019-08-13 18:33:36.355  INFO 31794 --- [           main] com.example.sec.AuthApplication          : Starting AuthApplication on meren-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC with PID 31794 (/home/meren/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.9.RELEASE/auth/target/classes started by meren in /home/meren/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.9.RELEASE/auth)
2019-08-13 18:33:36.357  INFO 31794 --- [           main] com.example.sec.AuthApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-08-13 18:33:37.389  INFO 31794 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-08-13 18:33:37.419  INFO 31794 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-08-13 18:33:37.419  INFO 31794 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.22]
2019-08-13 18:33:37.492  INFO 31794 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-08-13 18:33:37.493  INFO 31794 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1097 ms
2019-08-13 18:33:37.717  INFO 31794 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@3c98781a, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@6d5c2745, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@663bb8ef, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@1b1c538d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@e4e1ef5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@4375b013, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@1947596f, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@5de6cf3a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@3f736a16, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@7e446d92, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@31dfc6f5, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@3af7d855]
2019-08-13 18:33:37.860  INFO 31794 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-08-13 18:33:38.048  INFO 31794 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-08-13 18:33:38.052  INFO 31794 --- [           main] com.example.sec.AuthApplication          : Started AuthApplication in 1.954 seconds (JVM running for 2.394)
2019-08-13 18:33:44.741  INFO 31794 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-08-13 18:33:44.741  INFO 31794 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-08-13 18:33:44.751  INFO 31794 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 10 ms
2019-08-13 18:33:53.838 ERROR 31794 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : HikariPool-1 - dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
```

***Application properties***

```
app.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/auth?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Turkey
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
```

***App***

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AuthApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

***Config***

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, enabled from users where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, authority from auth where username=?")
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/user").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN").antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN").and().httpBasic();
    }

}
```

***Controller***

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String user() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return "You are logged in as "+authentication.getName()+" and role is "+ authentication.getAuthorities().toString();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String admin() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return "You are logged in as "+authentication.getName()+" and role is "+ authentication.getAuthorities().toString();
    }
}
```

[image: Database]
[image: Table]
[image: Table]

Comment: Logs seem to show incorrect HikariCP configuration. See `HikariPool-1 - dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.`.

Comment: what can i do? What will i change?

Comment: I would suggest to first get bare bones setup with HikariCP working and then build other things on top of it. See https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-jdbc-mysql-hikaricp-example/ for setting it up.